# optimization network models

Tags: optimization, network-flow, operations-research

This is a question from Wane Winston 's Book.
[image]

I don't understand how to do this. I tried to do it this way but it doesn't seem to work.

Let $C_{ij}$ be the cost of using box of i
$ i>=j$
Then I found $C_{0,17}=1017$
$C_{0,18}=1035\\    
C_{0,19}=1054\\  
C_{0,24}=1078 ...\\  
C_{0,33}=1167  \\
C_{17,18}=1018  \\
C_{17,19}=1037  \\
C_{17,24}=1061....\\  
C_{17,33}=1150  \\
...  \\
C_{30,33}=1033$
Then when I use Dijkstra's Algorithm the shortest distance to each node would be from node 0?
How can I solve this problem?